compilation failed for package 'mixer'
I was trying to install a R package "mixer". However, this package is old and has been removed from CRAN, so I have to install it from archive. Here is the archive:
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mixer/
I've already installed latest devtools, and tried both of these:
library(devtools)
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mixer/mixer_1.9.tar.gz")
install_version("mixer", "1.9")

And they returned error, like this:
Error: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (scalar and rank-1)
make: *** [D:/R/R-4.3.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:289: dgetv0.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mixer'
* removing 'D:/R/R-4.3.2/library/mixer'

I've also tried download tar.gz document from archive and install this package from my own computer. It still failed. I think this error may be related to gfortran, gcc, verison of fortran compiler or something like this, but I'm not very clear about these things. Here is detailed error code:
> install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mixer/mixer_1.9.tar.gz")
Downloading package from url: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/mixer/mixer_1.9.tar.gz
── R CMD build ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\甜茶\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpkx5vCR\remotes54f838cb63f1\mixer/DESCRIPTION' (368ms)
─  preparing 'mixer': (869ms)
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
─  building 'mixer_1.9.tar.gz'
   
* installing *source* package 'mixer' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.3.0'
using Fortran compiler: 'GNU Fortran (GCC) 12.3.0'
using C++ compiler: 'g++.exe (GCC) 12.3.0'
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Barycenters.cc -o Barycenters.o
Barycenters.cc: In member function 'void ermg::Barycenters::initFromClass(const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<int>&)':
Barycenters.cc:91:12: warning: variable 'ind1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   91 |     int s, ind1, ind2;
      |            ^~~~
Barycenters.cc: In member function 'void ermg::Barycenters::kmeansUpdate(int, int)':
Barycenters.cc:122:30: warning: variable 'ind1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  122 |     int s = _Xadj[i].size(), ind1, ind2;
      |                              ^~~~
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Em.cc -o Em.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c EmCore.cc -o EmCore.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Emd.cc -o Emd.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Ermg.cc -o Ermg.o
In file included from ./Barycenters.h:36,
                 from ./Ermg.h:38,
                 from Ermg.cc:20:
./SparseMatrix.h: In instantiation of 'void ermg::SparseMatrix<Content, Container>::laplacianMatrixProduct(double*, double*) [with Content = int; Container = std::vector<int>]':
./SparseMatrix.h:346:4:   required from 'std::vector<double>& ermg::SparseMatrix<Content, Container>::secondEigenVector() [with Content = int; Container = std::vector<int>]'
Ermg.cc:267:51:   required from here
./SparseMatrix.h:87:13: warning: variable 'ind1' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   87 |         int ind1=-1, ind2;
      |             ^~~~
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c Graph.cc -o Graph.o
Graph.cc: In member function 'std::vector<std::vector<int> > ermg::Graph::getMatrix()':
Graph.cc:45:9: warning: variable 'previd' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   45 |     int previd = 0;
      |         ^~~~~~
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c GraphReader.cc -o GraphReader.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ModelDesigner.cc -o ModelDesigner.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ModelImprover.cc -o ModelImprover.o
ModelImprover.cc: In member function 'void ermg::ModelImprover::improveLikelihoodsSpeed(ermg::EmCore&)':
ModelImprover.cc:212:47: warning: 'kselect' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  212 |                  &&(_imove_usedtosplit[kselect-1] == _imove[kselect-1]) ){
      |                                        ~~~~~~~^~
ModelImprover.cc:166:15: note: 'kselect' was declared here
  166 |           int kselect;
      |               ^~~~~~~
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c OCEm.cc -o OCEm.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c OEm.cc -o OEm.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c SOCEm.cc -o SOCEm.o
g++ -std=gnu++17  -I"D:/R/R-4.3.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"D:/R/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I.   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c VEstep_R.cc -o VEstep_R.o
In file included from VEstep_R.cc:7:
matrix.h:43:20: warning: 'not_implemented' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   43 | static const char *not_implemented = "Not yet implemented";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:42:20: warning: 'not_square_matrix' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   42 | static const char *not_square_matrix = "Not a squared Matrix";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:41:20: warning: 'out_of_dims' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   41 | static const char *out_of_dims     = "Index out of matrix dimensions";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:40:20: warning: 'not_scalar' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   40 | static const char *not_scalar      = "Matrix can't be trasformed to scalar";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:39:20: warning: 'not_dims_match' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   39 | static const char *not_dims_match  = "Matrix dimensions don't match";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.h:38:20: warning: 'not_same_dims' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   38 | static const char *not_same_dims   = "Matrix don't have the same dimensions";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from matrix.h:33:
util.h:48:20: warning: 'str_ctxt' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   48 | static const char *str_ctxt = "Matrix";
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
util.h:47:12: warning: 'Msg_level' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
   47 | static int Msg_level = 1;
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
In member function 'const double* Matrix::getData() const',
    inlined from 'Matrix Normalize(const Matrix&, const char*)' at matrix.h:1203:33,
    inlined from 'void VEstep_(int&, int&, double*, double*, double*, double*, double&, double&, double&, int&, int&, double*, int&)' at VEstep_R.cc:79:20:
matrix.h:425:60: warning: pointer used after 'void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)' [-Wuse-after-free]
  425 |     const double *getData() const { return( link_->matrix_ ) ; }
      |                                                            ^
In member function 'void Matrix::deleteLink()',
    inlined from 'void Matrix::deleteLink()' at matrix.h:93:8,
    inlined from 'Matrix::~Matrix()' at matrix.h:226:17,
    inlined from 'void VEstep_(int&, int&, double*, double*, double*, double*, double&, double&, double&, int&, int&, double*, int&)' at VEstep_R.cc:78:14:
matrix.h:98:14: note: call to 'void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)' here
   98 |       delete link_;
      |              ^~~~~
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dasum.f -o dasum.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c daxpy.f -o daxpy.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dcopy.f -o dcopy.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c ddot.f -o ddot.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dgemv.f -o dgemv.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dgeqr2.f -o dgeqr2.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dger.f -o dger.o
gfortran      -O2  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c dgetv0.f -o dgetv0.o
dgetv0.f:404:32:

  367 |           call dvout (logfil, 1, rnorm0, ndigit,
      |                                 2
......
  404 |          call dvout (logfil, n, resid, ndigit,
      |                                1
Error: Rank mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (scalar and rank-1)
make: *** [D:/R/R-4.3.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:289: dgetv0.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mixer'
* removing 'D:/R/R-4.3.2/library/mixer'

It seems that this problem is caused by some detailed content in the package. Is there any simple method to get rid of it or I have to dive into details of the code of this package?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

If I had to install an older package, I would fetch a Docker image with R of approximate age to when mixer was still installable and go from there.

@Roman Luštrik Thank you. I would try it.

It's often the case that there's a different package on CRAN that will do whatever you wanted to do with an archived package, probably faster and better.  Can you tell us what functions / capabilities you are looking for?
